# Unable to drag items in QGraphicsView after reimplementing mousePressEvent

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

here is the situation:
I have QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem.
When I do not implement mouse events, I can drag items. 
But when I implement in the QGraphicsView

```
class MyView: public QGraphicsView {
...
protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
...
}
```

I can't drag items anymore.

Should I implement somehow Mouse events for the QGraphicsItem and translate them from the QGraphicsView?

Currently, in QGraphicsItem I don't have these methods and use defaults.
Thank you.

Comment: You either implement the moving of QGraphicsItem yourself, or call super for mouseMoveEvent, mouseReleaseEvent and mousePressEvent to continue processing the events inside the QGraphicsScene.

Comment: Daniele, thank you. The calling super mouseMoveEvent works perfectly.
Could you outline it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either implement the moving of `QGraphicsItem` yourself, or call super for `mouseMoveEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mousePressEvent` to continue processing the events inside the `QGraphicsScene`.